# railsでcheck_box_tagの値を渡す方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsで管理画面を作っています。
その中でリストから選択したデータを参照するデータだけをExcelファイルで見れる機能を作ろうとしていますが、チェックされた値をどうやって渡せるのかがわからなくて詰まっているところです。
下記は現在自分のコードでございます。

```
table.table.table-bordered.table-striped
  thead
    tr
      th
      th #
      th 会社コード
  tbody
    - @companies.each do |company|
      tr
        td = check_box_tag 'company_ids[]', company.Id, id
        td.text-right = company.Id
        td = company.CompanyCode
        td.text-center = link_to '詳細', company
        td = link_to '修正', edit_company_path(company)
        td = link_to '削除', company, data: {:confirm => '本当に削除してもよろしいでしょうか？'}, :method => :delete


= link_to 'Excelダウンロード', companies_path(format: 'xls')
```

controller

```
before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /company
def index
  @companies = Company.all

  @book = Book.where(CompanyId: params[:company_ids])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xls
  end
end

# GET /company/1
def show
end

# GET /company/new
def new
  @company = Company.new
end

# GET /company/1/edit
def edit
end

(省略)

private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_company
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
end

# Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:CompanyCode)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view 側に form_for あるいは form_tag が記述されていないのが気になりますが、
とりあえず controller の Strong Parameter を以下のようにしてみてください。

```
def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:company_ids => [])
end
```

そして def index の where は以下のように。

```
@book = Book.where(company_id: company_params[:company_ids])
```

form_for および form_tag については以下を参考にしてください。
http://qiita.com/shunsuke227ono/items/7accec12eef6d89b0aa9